# Como obter um identificador único por dispositivo do IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, apple

No desenvolvimento para **Android** é possível definir se um smartphone é único através de seu **IMEI** ou **MAC**, e talvez não seja a melhor forma de identificar unicamente um dispositivo móvel, porém funciona muito bem.

Por outro lado a **Apple** não permite mais que os desenvolvedores obtenham nem o **MAC** e nem o **IMEI** dos dispositivos móveis.

Estou ciente que é possível usar `CFUUIDCreate` para obter um Identificador único, porém esse identificador só estará disponível até que o usuário desinstale a aplicação, e se voltar a instalar novamente o identificador será outro.

Como obter uma identificação única para um dispositivo IOS, independente se o usuário desinstalou a aplicação?

Comment: Não entendo porque essa pergunta recebeu um voto de fechamento por estar fora do escopo uma vez que segundo a "Central de ajuda", essa pergunta se encaixa no tópico "um problema específico de programação", ou seja o problema é uma segunda alternativa de como identificar um dispositivo sem ser pelo IMEI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução possível é salvar o identificador no Keychain. Dessa forma há como recuperá-lo caso o usuário delete o app e instale novamente.
Existem algumas bibliotecas que implementam essa funcionalidade, como por exemplo [FCUUID](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/FCUUID).

No iOS 11 a Apple introduziu o DeviceCheck framework, que permite salvar dois bits que são persistidos mesmo se o app for reinstalado ou o usuarío transferir dados de um dispositivo para outro. Esse [vídeo](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/702/) do WWDC explica com funciona, a partir do minuto 24.